# What is the probability that after pulling out of a card deck 3 heart cards, that the 4th card will be also a heart?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

What is the probability that after pulling out of a card deck 3 heart cards, that the 4th card will be also a heart? There are 52 cards in the deck and there is no replacement.

$$P(4\text{th heart} | 3 \text{ first hearts}) = \frac{P(4\text{th heart}\cap 3\text{ first hearts})}{P(3\text{ firsthearts})}$$

How do you calculate this probability:
$P(4\text{th heart}\cap 3\text{ first hearts})$

Comment: How many cards are in the deck? How are you drawing them? With replacement or not?

Comment: 52 cards no replacement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things. You can use the more intuitive meaning of conditional probability

> The probability of $P(X|Y)$ is the probability that $X$ will happen if you **know** that $Y$ already happened.

Well, if you know that the first three cards were hearts, then the probability that the fourth card will be a heart is equal to the probability of drawing a heart out of a deck of $49$ cards of which $10$ are hearts.

---

Of course, you can also go with the original attempt. Then the event

> The first three cards were hearts and the fourth card was a heart

Is the same event as

> The first four cards were all hearts.

Comment: Thank you that makes perfect sense! :)

Comment: In your first explanation the prob is 10/49, but in the second explanation the prob is (13*12*11*10)/(52*51*50*49). Am I thinking wrong?

Comment: @Mathguy007 You are correct. However, the number $\frac{10}{49}$ is the probability $P(X|Y)$, and the second number is the probability $P(X\cap Y)$

Comment: arghhh Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @Mathguy007 If you divide the second number by $P(Y) = \frac{13\cdot 12\cdot 11}{52\cdot 51\cdot 50}$, you get the first number.

Answer (score 0):

Initially you have 13 hearts in 52 cards deck so probability of first heart is 13/52.

Then you have 12 hearts in 51 cards deck => probability of second heart given first heart is 12/51. And probability of first two hearts is $\frac{13}{52}\cdot\frac{12}{51}$.

Then you can proceed up to 4 pulled cards.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

After pulling out $3$ hearts there are $49$ cards left and $10$ of them are hearts (preassumed that it is a normal deck). So the probability that at that stage a heart will be drawn is...

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning, you have a $\frac {13}{52}$ chance of choosing a Heart. After that is removed, you now have $12$ cards out of $51$. So you now have a $\frac {12}{51}$ chance of choosing a Heart.

Continuing this on, we get $$\frac {13}{52}\times\frac {12}{51}\times\frac {11}{50}\times\frac {10}{49}=\boxed{\frac {11}{4165}}$$

Which comes out to be about $0.3\%$.